# Rule-based symbology in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, line, visualisation, rule-based

I'm trying to create the following rule based expression for displaying a line:
if column `"riparian Veg"` has a *'Yes'* entered into it then display the line  but if another column titled `"Primary"` has *'Riparian vegetation management'* entered into it then do not display the line.

How do I create this expression in QGIS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the symbology tab of the properties -

Select Rule-based

For the filter enter "riparian Veg" = 'Yes' AND NOT "Primary" = 'Riparian vegetation management'

capitalization matters - it has to match the field names and attribute values. I just copied what's in your question. If that's not exactly what's in your layer, it won't work.

You use the query builder (the curly E button next to the filter text box) to create this filter with point-and-click. Expand the Fields and Values tree to get your fields. Double-click a field to enter it into the expression. When a field is highlighted, you can click on Values to get a list of the values in the attribute table. Double click a value to enter it into the expression.